# How can use bokeh plotted graph url in website

Tags: javascript, html, bokeh

Using bokeh creating a graph. From server side, i am getting a url.
In a new tab url is working fine.
But inside a web i can not use this url. It showing same origin issue.

Refused to display 'http://ip:port/bokehplot/PythonProcess1507699537076_ac345201-3c2e-4273-9239-71e15fff4f67/11' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'X-Frame-Options' is a response header set by the server from which you are requesting the resource. They have set the header to SAMEORIGIN in this case, which means that they have disallowed loading of the resource in an iframe outside of their domain.

you can set this header to **ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/** (The page can only be displayed in a frame on the specified origin.) or  **ALLOW-ALL**

eg: **response.headers["X-FRAME-OPTIONS"] = "ALLOW-ALL"**

Hope this would resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Shemeem. 
It is working fine. Now i can load inside iframe.